# Как прогнать циклов dict в Python?

Tags: python

Есть такая структура dict

print(name)

```
{'Натариус': ['2446614', '2446615'], 'Traiding': ['2446600', '2446601', '2446602', '2446603', '2446604', '2446605', '2446606', '2446648', '2446647', '2446725', '2446715', '2446613', '2446687'], 'Бар Шелк': ['2446622', '2446612'], 'БиТел Телеком': ['2446633', '2446699'], 'СТС Логистик': ['2446650', '2446651', '2446652', '2446653', '2446654'] и т д
```

т.е. есть ключ Натариус, у него значение list из двух элементов
Дальше ключе Traiding, у него значение List из 13 элементов

Как прогнать через цикл for такую структуру, что бы у меня на каждом шагу был доступ к ключу и текущему значению.

Пробую вот так

```
for key in name:
    for lst in name.values():
```

Но он во втором цикле идет по всем значениям, а мне надо что бы сначало у первого ключа, потом у второго и т д.

Comment: И, всё-таки, "нотариус".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял:

```
name = {'Натариус': ['2446614', '2446615'], 'Traiding': ['2446600', '2446601', '2446602', '2446603', '2446604', '2446605', '2446606', '2446648', '2446647', '2446725', '2446715', '2446613', '2446687'], 'Бар Шелк': ['2446622', '2446612'], 'БиТел Телеком': ['2446633', '2446699'], 'СТС Логистик': ['2446650', '2446651', '2446652', '2446653', '2446654']}
for key, value in name.items():
    for i in value:
        print(f"{key}:\t{i}")
```